# Presento dificultades para compartir una carpeta entre Windows 10 y Ubuntu a través de un máquina virtual debido a permisos de lectura

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualización

[image]

Les pongo en contexto. Monté el ISO de Ubuntu 22 en una máquina virtual usando la herramienta Virtual Box. Despúes de iniciar el sistema he tratado de compartir una carpeta o directorio entre mi sistema original Windows 10 y ese Ubuntu virtualizado. El problema es que al acceder al directorio me sale un cartel de que no poseo permisos de lectura.

Por cierto, la opción de Drop and Play tampoco me funciona, aún despúes de ponerlo bidireccional. Si saben alguna forma para enviar carpetas de Windows 10 a Ubuntu necesito de vuestra ayuda. Gracias!

Comment: Hola Aran. ¿Qué pasos seguiste para compartir la carpeta?

Comment: Hola @caprilo, gracias por ser el primero en responder. Lo que hice para compartir la carpeta fue acceder a preferencias de carpeta compartida y desde esa pestaña gestioné mi carpeta compartida, donde dice carpetas de la máquina.

Comment: ¿Tienes instaladas las Guest Additions?

Comment: @caprilo creo que si bro. Usas telegram o whatsapp ? Para ver si me puedes ayudar mejor por ahi porfavor.